# Convert a relative path (mp3) from a master file path (playlist) using python pathlib

Tags: python, pathlib

I have three files

1. My python file running in an unimportant different folder: C:\DD\CC\BB\AA\code.py
2. A playlist file "C:\ZZ\XX\Playlist.pls" which points to ....\mp3\song.mp3
3. The C:\mp3\song.mp3 file.

What I want is to get the location of the mp3 as an absolute path. But every attemp I try I get everything related to whenever the code.py file is.

```
import pathlib
plMaster = pathlib.Path(r"C:\ZZ\XX\Playlist.pls")
plSlave = pathlib.Path(r"..\..\mp3\song.mp3")
```

I have tried plSlave.absolute() and gives me "C:\DD\CC\BB\AA....\mp3\song.mp3"
Using relative_to doesn't work. I feel like I am doing such an easy task but I must be missing something because I can't find any function that lets me set **the reference** to compute the relative path.

Note: I already have parsed the pls file, and have the string r"....\mp3\song.mp3" extracted. I just need to get the path "C:\mp3\song.mp3" knowing that they are relative to the pls. (Not relative to the code.py)

Comment: You need some library that can parse .pls files...

Comment: .pls files seem to be basically .ini files, so you should be able to use [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) in the standard library

Comment: I already parsed the pls. I just need to obtain the absolute path to the mp3, knowing the relative path (String) and the absolute location of the pls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a Windows version of Python, this is fairly easy. You can join the directory of `plMaster` (`plMaster.parent`) with the relative path of `plSlave`, then resolve the path using `resolve()`. You can use `strict=False` to force the resolve even if the path components aren't found.

This worked for me:

```
>>> plMaster = pathlib.Path(r"C:\ZZ\XX\Playlist.pls")
>>> plSlave = pathlib.Path(r"..\..\mp3\song.mp3")
>>> plMaster.parent.joinpath(plSlave).resolve(strict=False)
WindowsPath('C:/mp3/song.mp3')
```

If you're on a Unix version of Python, using Windows paths, I couldn't get this to work no matter what I tried, even using `pathlib.PureWindowsPath()`.

Comment: This one is a little bit convoluted, but looks like it is working, and uses pathlib exclusively. So I am going to mark as solved over my solution.

I need that it works in Linux, but I will be using Linux paths there (at least the master). So plMaster would be some /sda or whatever the raspberry assign to an external drive that would contain the music.

Answer (score 1):

Might well be a better method here, but you can use `pathlib.Path.parents` and `pathlib.Path.parts` to extract some useful info here and get where you are going

```py
new_relative_path = r"..\..\mp3\song.mp3" #however you got this from reading your .pls file or whatever
pls_path = pathlib.Path(r'C:\ZZ\XX\Playlist.pls')
relative_save = pathlib.Path(new_relativePath)

n = relative_save.parts.count('..')

new_path = pls_path.parents[n-1].joinpath(*relative_save.parts[n:])
```

The key thing here is that you are going to navigate up the original path (the `pls_path`) `n` times (so `n-1` since we start at 0), and then you are going to append to that whatever your new relative path is, stripping the `'..'` segments from the beginning of it.

Comment: That was my last resource, build my own function to parse it. I have to say that I really like how it looks like but @sj95126 figure it out a way using the pathlib functions.

Comment: oh yea just using `.resolve()` is the way to go if you can get around the os-path-differences

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I was waiting for other answers I manage to figure it out ditching pathlib and using os instead.

```
import os
plMaster = r"C:\ZZ\XX\Playlist.pls"
plSlave = r"..\..\mp3\song.mp3"
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(plMaster))
os.path.abspath(plSlave)
```